# Android storing array list locally and using it

Tags: android, arrays, arraylist

We have an app in which we have few Array list defined as below

```
    public final static ArrayList<String> Arraylist1= new ArrayList<String>(){{
    }};
    public final static ArrayList<String> Arraylist2= new ArrayList<String>(){{
    }};
    public final static ArrayList<String> Arraylist3= new ArrayList<String>(){{
    }};
```

We are updating this array list in between whenever network is available.So it will be like synchronizing the app.Problem we face now is, each time when the app starts it will initialize the array-list and waits for the first synchronization. Is there a way to store the updated array-list locally so that even the synchronization wont happen because of network unavailability, it wont effect the app functionality.

Comment: You can save them in shared preferences and update them each time you have new data

Answer (score 0):

You have to store locally what you need, and in case of network unavailability you use the local "older" version.

The main possibilities are 3:

1. Shared Preferences: file that can be shared among apps or private and it is composed with a couple key-value to store data.
2. SqlLite DB: a normal relational database.
3. Files, e.g. json files with your own structure. (Here you are completely free)

Answer (score 0):

you can make something like this

```
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();

editor.putString(Name, n);
editor.putString(Phone, ph);
editor.putString(Email, e);
editor.commit();
```

and after you just nead to read the values and update the server...

Or you can store the in a file and when have connection to the internet upload

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what kind of data you deal with. If its lots and heavy data i wouldn't prefer sharedPreferences.

best practice will be saving that data in Sqlite database and retrieving back when required.

another approach is to make the arraylist static like you have done. that will keep values for certain period of time. and will be faster than shared preferences or Sqlite DB to read and write. but you cant count on static variables. their lifetime depends on GC.